# Functional programming javascript find in list

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, refactoring

I want to get the first element in a array that matchs a function in O(n) using functional (maybe pure) style. Note im using the [functional.js](http://functionaljs.com/) library, but its not that important.

Code to REFACTOR to a pure functional way:

```
var result = fjs.first(function(value){
    return value.id == notification.id;
},array);
```

I want to refactor it by extracting out the .id for both objects and pass in the notification object, right now its in above scope

So i tried to first map then find. But its super ugly (in my opinion).

```
var equal = fjs.curry(function(arg1, arg2){ // curry allows for partial functions... i think... 
                return arg1 == arg2
            });
var equalNotificationId = fts.equal(notification.id); // partial function of equal for notification.id number

var newIdArray = fts.map(fts.prop("id"),array);
var result     = fts.first(equalNotificationId , newIdArray );
```

Im looking to refactor this functionaly maybe as pure as possible? Is there a better way?

Comment: `O(2n)` *is* `O(n)`. Either way, if the library supports lazy evaluation (don't know if it does and also not sure if this is the right term), then it would only map the elements when needed. For example in Immutable.js: http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/#lazy-seq .

Comment: right but is this the best way to do it? trying to extract out the .id for both objects and to pass in notification object.

Comment: sorry my question was bad i edited it, im not focused on time, its more about refactoring for a pure functional way.

Comment: Is the purpose of newId Array to just turn an array of objects into an array of id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to refactor it but if anyone has anything else to bring to this ill give them the points.

```
//example data
var notification = {id:10};
var array = [{id:11},{id:6},{id:10},{id:3},{id:1}];

//equal function
var equal = fts.curry(function(arg1,arg2){
                return arg1 == arg2;
            });

//returns object in array with id 10.
 var result = fjs.first(fts.compose(equal(notification.id),fts.prop("id")),array);
```